# php apache2 envirument variable not set

Tags: development-environment, apache2.4, ubuntu-15.04

i'm trying to set a envirument variable on my server for my php apps, this seems to work on the test server, but live (the config is different thou) the variable does not get passed to php.

## my setup:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    #setEnv APPLICATION_ENV production #this also does not work
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/.htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
```

i do use nginx in front of apache as a proxy, but this should not matter.

`phpinfo()` does include env variables like `_SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"]` which is set by unique_id mod. but their is **no** `_["APPLICATION_ENV"]`

the fakt i find so little about this problem in the internet, proves my point that this should "just work"

could their be some config which i messed up?
could have a module like 'mod_security2' have some impact?

i can give more information about my server, if needed, but not shure what could help.